# What is the difference between child and descendant XPath axes?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

```
<div class='ABC'>
    <a href='url.com'></a>
    <div class='XXX'></a>
    <div id='EDF'>
        <a href='url.com'></a>
    </div>  
    <div class='XYZ'></div>
</div>
```

As per my understanding `//div[@class='ABC'//child::*]` should yield search result of 4 and `//div[@class='ABC'//descendant::*]` should yield 5. But, in reality, both are yielding search result of 5.

Can anyone help me understand the difference?

Comment: By using "//" you are implicitly using the descendant axis. `X//child::*` is to all intents another way of saying `X/descendant::*`. You could also write it as `X//*`. Writing `X//descendant::*` is redundant and probably inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, fix your markup to be well-formed (`<div>` cannot be closed with a `</a>`):

```
<div class='ABC'>
    <a href='url.com'></a>
    <div class='XXX'></div>
    <div id='EDF'>
        <a href='url.com'></a>
    </div>  
    <div class='XYZ'></div>
</div>
```

Then, fix your XPath syntax:

1. `count(//div[@class='ABC']/child::*)` returns 4.
2. `count(//div[@class='ABC']/descendant::*)` returns 5.

Which should align with your expectation that the ***XPath child axis selects immediate children only while the XPath descendant axis selects children and children's children recursively***.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your syntax is wrong, using the following XPath's I get 2 children and 5 descendants

```
//div[@class='ABC']/child::*
//div[@class='ABC']/descendant::*
```